# Склоняются ли фамилии?

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Склоняются ли фамилии и, если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для склонения фамилий существует несколько правил.
Мужские и женские славянские фамилии, заканчивающиеся на -ов, -ин, -ова, -ина, склоняются в соответствии с правилами русского языка.
Пример: *Иванов - Иванова, Красина - Красина, Петрова - Петровой, Васина - Васиной*.
Мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на безударное А и ИЯ, тоже склоняются.
Пример: *Окуджава - Окуджавы, Митта - Митты. Берия - Берии*.
При этом, мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на -ИА, не склоняются.
Пример: *Гамсахурдиа*.
Иностранные фамилии, оканчивающиеся на А и Я, не склоняются.
Пример: *Золя, Дюма*.
Женские и мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на "-ко", не склоняются.
Пример: *Короленко, Довженко*.
В случае окончания "-чук", склоняются только мужские фамилии, женские остаются без изменений.
Пример: *Леодин Кравчук - Леодина Кравчука, Мария Николайчук - Марии Николайчук.*
Фамилии, оканчивающиеся на остальные гласыные (кроме А), не склоняются.
Примеры: *Фальконе, Камдесю, Ротару, Висконти и т.д.*

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу.
Из наиболее чаcтых случаев надо отметить:

1. Фамилии на -ых, -их не склоняются.
2. Фамилии, мужские и женские, оканчиающиеся на -а - обычно **склоняются**, независимо от места ударения, исключение сделано только для **французских фамилий** (видимо по историческим причинам, ударность последнего слога здесь не является существеной).
3. Некоторые типы фамилий допускают двойственную парадигму склонения: Леденец -  Леденца и Леденеца, Жемужина - Жемчужине и Жумчужиной и т.д.

Посмотрите тут, более или менее полный обзор.
http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_104